# Lebesgue measure on (0,1]

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $\Omega = (0,1]$ and $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}((0,1])$. Let $\{b\}$ be a subset of $(0,1]$. The Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda((a,b]) = b - a$ for any $ (a,b] \subseteq (0,1]$

I have been trying to prove that $\lambda(\{b\}) = 0$

So far I have: $\{b\} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[b-1/n,b+1/n]$, since $\lambda((a,b]) = \lambda([a,b])$ we have $\lambda(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[b-1/n,b+1/n])= b - b = 0 $

Am I going in the right direction with this proof?

Comment: I assume $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure?  Your answer will depend on your definition of Lebesgue measure.  If you have no idea how to do a problem, one good start is to write down the definitions involved.  Your question is subject to being closed because you showed no effort of your own.  Are you trying to emulate your username?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated the main post with some more details.

Comment: Your argument is basically right, but still a bit off.  You say "since $\lambda((a,b]) = \lambda([a,b])$" with no proof.  You can avoid using that if you start with $\{b\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(b-1/n,b+1/n]$.  And put in the calculation $\lambda((b-1/n,b+1/n]) = (b+1/n)-(b-1/n) = 2/n$, and say that this converges to $0$.  Whether that is enough depends on the definition of Lebesgue measure, which you have not shown, and which can be different from one book to another.

Comment: You can do in a simpler way. Just see that $\{b\} = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(b-1/n,b+1/n]$, so we have $\lambda(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(b-1/n,b+1/n])= \lim_n \lambda(b-1/n,b+1/n] = \lim_n  \frac{2}{n} = 0 $.